# Custom Notification showing like image

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, custom-notification

I'm Implementing a custom notification layout with two buttons but why its shows like Image

and how to do event on button click of notification

[image]

what I'm doing wrong

**I want to show the notification like this**

[image]

Notification Class

```
public class NotificationService {

public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "watistant_notification";
Context context;

public NotificationService(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


public void callNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    RemoteViews notification_layout_small = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.notification_layout_small);
    RemoteViews notification_layout = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.notification_layout);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_circle)
            .setContentTitle("Reminder")
            .setContentText("You are dehydrating..........")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(notification_layout_small)
            .setCustomBigContentView(notification_layout)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build();

        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        builder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), builder.build());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check following lines of code, that would help you to trigger button click of notification click

Add below code in your callNotification() method

```
Notification notification = null;
  Intent skip = new Intent(mContext, NotificationActionService.class);
                skip.setAction(101);//replace with your custom value
                skip.putExtra("test", "test");

                PendingIntent pendingIntentYes = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 12345, skip, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Intent drink = new Intent(mContext, NotificationActionService.class);//attach all keys starting with wzrk_ to your notification extras
                drink.setAction(102);//replace with your custom value

                PendingIntent pendingIntentNo = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 123456, drink, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setSound(soundUri)
                        .setChannelId(channelId)
                        .addAction("your icon", "skip", pendingIntentYes) //Action Button 1, update the ic_launcher with a image present in your 
                        .addAction("your icon", "dring",pendingIntentNo) // Action Button 2, maximum 3 allowed
                         .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .build();

public class NotificationActionService extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Bundle answerBundle = intent.getExtras();

        switch (action){

            case 101:

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                intent1.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                context.startActivity(intent1);

                break;
            case 102:
                break;
        }
        NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(context);
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        context.sendBroadcast(it);

    }


}
```

**Note** : Dont forget to declare in in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationActionService" />
```

Comment: I don't want to use stock setAction I want to triggerd from my button which is in notification layout